# JFileChooser save dialog filename is modified or acted upon before approveSelection() is called

Tags: java, swing, filenames, jfilechooser, file-writing

I have a FileSaver class that extends the JFileChooser class. The constructor defines some file filters, sets the default file filter and calls `setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false)`. When the user clicks a button, a FileSaver object is created and `showSaveDialog()` is called for it. The FileSaver class overrides `approveSelection()` so that it can validate the filename entered before calling `super.approveSelection()`.

This is fine for most filenames entered, but if the filename contains a question mark ("?") or asterisk ("*") then `approveSelection()` is not called and a new file filter is created (and appears set while the program mainly treats the file filter as its previous setting) with the filename as the description. Would it be possible to treat these filenames like any others (such that `approveSelection()` is called and the selected file set accordingly)?

Also, it seems as though a filename containing a forward slash ("/") is treated as a path relative to the current directory and thus `getSelectedFile().getName()` only returns the part of the filename after the slash (or removing a slash at the end of the filename) and the part before appended to the directory path. Would it be possible for `approveSelection()` to retrieve the full filename for validation and not alter the directory?

Comment: Instead of describing your code over 3 very long paragraph, rather provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow/help/mcve/).

Answer (score 1):

Try add this class on your JFileChooser class, this class implements **getApproveSelectionAction** method of **WindowsFileChooserUI**:

```
   public class MyFileChooser extends JFileChooser{


      @Override
      protected void setUI(ComponentUI newUI) {
        super.setUI(new CustomFileChooserUI(this));
      }



      private static boolean isGlobPattern(String filename) {
                return ((File.separatorChar == '\\' && (filename.indexOf('*') >= 0
                                                          || filename.indexOf('?') >= 0))
                        || (File.separatorChar == '/' && (filename.indexOf('*') >= 0
                                                          || filename.indexOf('?') >= 0
                                                          || filename.indexOf('[') >= 0)));
       }

      public class CustomFileChooserUI extends WindowsFileChooserUI {

                JFileChooser jfileChooser;

                public CustomFileChooserUI(JFileChooser b) {
                  super(b);
                  jfileChooser = b;
                }

                @Override
                protected void createModel() {
                  super.createModel();
                }

                @Override
                public Action getApproveSelectionAction() {
                  return new ApproveSelectionAction() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                      String filename = getFileName();
                      if(isGlobPattern(filename)){
                        // your code here
                        return;
                      }
                      super.actionPerformed(e);
                    }
                  };
                }

       }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was aware my problem likely would not be trivially solvable. Although I'm no longer working on this project, I'm interested in knowing how to fix this issue. I think I have a high-level understanding of your code and have managed to adapt it for my project, but when I attempt to create an instance of `MyFileChooser` I get a `NullPointerException` when calling `super.setUI(new CustomFileChooserUI(this))`. Any thoughts on why this might be?